# Regex Pattern for phone series 97890x00yz

Tags: java, regex

Regex Pattern for phone series 97890x00yz where x,y,z should not have same values ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: All other things except x,y and z are constant?. i.e, 97890 and 00 are constant or can they change?

Comment: they are constant..only x,y,z can vary

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work for you :

```
public static void main(String... strings) {
    // String s = "97890x00yz";
       String s = "9789010023"; // output true.
    System.out.println(s.matches("97890(\\d)00(?!\\1)(\\d)(?!\\1|\\2)\\d"));
    //String s = "9789010022"; same regex - output : false
}
```

Comment: can u explain the logic?

Comment: `()` captures everything inside it. SO you capture digits and `(?!)` is negative look-ahead.. It makes sure that the mentioned string doesn't follow..`\\1` refers to first captured group (digit) . `\\2` referes to second and so on.

Comment: thanx bro...could u help me with this string 978900x00x?

Comment: and 9789xyyyyy where x and y having diff values

Comment: help me with this regex..9789xyy000...im getting some error

Answer (score 0):

```
97890(\d)00(?!\1)(\d)(?!\2|\1)\d
```

You can try this.[**See demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/12)